# Inserir um select dentro de uma td ao dar duplo click é possivel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, table

Olá eu tenho uma tabela dinamica que funciona muito bem, mas como o campo é um input as pessoas podem digitar qualquer coisa, mas queria limitar esta edição usando as opções dos option, a tabela eu uso o `id="tblEditabel"` e nas linhas que irão funcionar com duplo click coloquei a classe `class="editavel"`, desta forma apenas os campos com a classe serão editados, estou usando comandos `mysql` para consulta ao banco. Segue a forma que se encontra hoje.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function() {
      if ($('td > input').length > 0) {
        return;
      }
      var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
      var novoElemento = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        value: conteudoOriginal
      });
      $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which;
        var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
        if (keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal) {
          var objeto = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "atualiza_tipo.html",
            data: {
              id: $(this).parents('tr').children().first().text(),
              campo: $(this).parent().attr('title'),
              valor: conteudoNovo
            }, //added this comma here
            success: function(result) {
              objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
              $('body').append(result);
            }
          })
        } else if (keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur'){
          $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
          }
      }));
      $(this).children().select();
    
        //} removed the extra } from here.
    });
 })
```

```css
table, td{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblEditavel" class="table table-striped table-hover">
 <thead>
   <tr>      
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Tipo</th>
       <th>Nome</th>
       <th>Data</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>        
   <tr>
   <td>123</td>
   <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Gerente</td>
   <td>Fulano</td>
   <td>01/10/2007</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

perceba que ao dar duplo click na coluna tipo a mesma insere um input para inserir qualquer outro tipo, o que eu queria seria limitar edição, eu consigo inserir o select mas não estou conseguindo popular os options, sei que terá q ser algo em ajax e está é a minha grande dificuldade.

Comment: Você consegue carregar um objeto com essas informações?

Comment: Mas qual exatamente é sua dificuldade ao incluir os options com dados de uma chamada `Ajax`? Já tem uma chamada que retorna os dados? No seu código já tem uma chamada `Ajax`, não seria nada muito diferente disso.  Aqui tem um exemplo bem simples que pode te ajudar: http://www.devmedia.com.br/populando-selects-dinamicamente-com-ajax-json-e-php/27658

Comment: Bom dia @VirgilioNovic da forma que se encontra eu trabalho normalmente, as informações inseridas no input são salvas no banco sem maiores complicaçoes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Além do objeto a ser carregado, tem a codificação do `select` e o valor selecionado para ficar como o último valor escolhido. Foi colocado um `var items` com 3 itens fixos o que pode ser feito é trazer as informações formatadas para que o `select` seja carregado.

Pode ser carregado via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) sem problemas, é só adicionar nesse código isso, mas, você poderia editar a sua pergunta e colocar o nome da tabela, dos campos e se está usando `PDO` ou `Mysqli` para proposta essa solução.

***Exemplo:***

```js
var items = [{
    value: 1,
    title: 'Gerente'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    title: 'Administrador'
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    title: 'Operário'
  }
];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(
    function() {
      if ($('td > input').length > 0) {
        return;
      }
      var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
      var novoElemento = $('<select/>');

      $.each(items, function(a, b) {        
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        if (b.title == conteudoOriginal) {
          opt.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }
        opt.value = b.value;
        opt.innerHTML = b.title;
        novoElemento[0].appendChild(opt);
      });
      novoElemento.bind('change', function() 
      {
        conteudoOriginal = $(this.name + " option:selected").text();
      });
      $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which;
        var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
        if (keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal) {
          var objeto = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "atualiza_tipo.html",
            data: {
              id: $(this).parents('tr').children().first().text(),
              campo: $(this).parent().attr('title'),
              valor: conteudoNovo
            }, //added this comma here
            success: function(result) {
              objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
              $('body').append(result);
            }
          })
        } else if (keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur') {
          $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
        }
      }));
      $(this).children().select();
    });
})
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblEditavel" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Gerente</td>
      <td>Fulano</td>
      <td>01/10/2007</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Administrador</td>
      <td>Fulano</td>
      <td>01/10/2007</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Operário</td>
      <td>Fulano</td>
      <td>01/10/2007</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic era exatamente a minha dúvida de onde colocar os dados dos options.

Answer (score 0):

Me ajudou muito o exemplo do combo, mas ele está com um problema, se você clicar no último combo e selecionar um item e depois no de cima e selecionar algo, o combo debaixo concatena a escolha do combo debaixo com o selecionado no combo de cima. Outra coisa, precisa clicar duas vezes. Fiz algumas alterações e acho que ficou bom! Agora é só clicar uma vez e não duplica os itens selecionados. Espero que gostem.

```
    <title>Tabela Editável</title>

    <!-- jquery - link cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap - link cdn -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var items = [{
            value: 1,
            title: 'Gerente'
          },
          {
            value: 2,
            title: 'Administrador'
          },
          {
            value: 3,
            title: 'Operário'
          }
        ];

        var lin_col = "0,-1";
        var lin_col_anterior = "-1,0";
        function infoCel(x, y){
            lin_col = x+","+y;  

        }

        $(document).ready(function() {


          $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').click(
            function() {
                //alert('Você  '+lin_col+' input  td '+lin_col_anterior);

                if(lin_col_anterior != lin_col) {                         
                      if ($('td > input').length > 0) {
                        return;
                      }
                      var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
                      var novoElemento = $('<select />');

                      $.each(items, function(a, b) {        
                        var opt = document.createElement("option");
                        if (b.title == conteudoOriginal) {
                          opt.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                        }
                        opt.value = b.value;
                        opt.innerHTML = b.title;
                        novoElemento[0].appendChild(opt);
                      });
                      novoElemento.bind('change', function() 
                      {
                        conteudoOriginal = $(this.name + " option:selected").text();
                      });
                      $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e) {
                        var keyCode = e.which;
                        var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
                        if (keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal) {
                          var objeto = $(this);
                              objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
                        } else if (keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur') {
                          $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
                        }
                      }));
                      $(this).children().select();
                  } else {
                        //$(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
                  }
                  lin_col_anterior = lin_col;
            });

        })

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table,td {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h4><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="tblEditavel" class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td onClick="infoCel(0, 0)">123</td>
          <td title="Nome" class="editavel" onClick="infoCel(0, 1)">Gerente</td>
          <td onClick="infoCel(0, 2)">Fulano</td>
          <td onClick="infoCel(0, 3)">01/10/2007</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td onClick="infoCel(1, 0)">123</td>
          <td title="Nome" class="editavel" onClick="infoCel(1, 1)">Administrador</td>
          <td onClick="infoCel(1, 2)">Fulano</td>
          <td onClick="infoCel(1, 3)">01/10/2007</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td onClick="infoCel(2, 0)">123</td>
          <td title="Nome" class="editavel" onClick="infoCel(2, 1)">Operário</td>
          <td onClick="infoCel(2, 2)">Fulano</td>
          <td onClick="infoCel(2, 3)">01/10/2007</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```